# .gitignore: How do I ignore nested directories?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following directory structure:

```
test/a
test/b/c
test/a/b/Ouput
test/c/d/e/Output
test/f/Output
```

I want to ignore all the "Output" directories under "test".  I tried `test/**/Output`, but it didn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @hammar, since v1.8.2 (March, 8th 2013), git accept ** in .gitignore files

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You said you want the `Output/` pattern to match only under the `test/` directory, so in the `test/` directory, create a `.gitignore` file with the contents:

```
Output/
```

If you put this pattern in your top-level `.gitignore` file, then it will match in **all** directories under the top directory.

Comment: What if I want to do it in my toplevel `.gitignore`?

Comment: @RamkumarRamachandra: Why don't you want it in your `test/.gitignore`? You've said that you only want the `Output` pattern to match under the `test` directory so this is where the pattern naturally belongs.

Comment: Consider `Output/` instead of `Output`. The question asks to ignore directories called `Output`.

Comment: No one answered the earlier question: Yes, this will also work in the top-level `.gitignore`.

Comment: It really saves the day!

Answer (score 40):

Since **version 1.8.2** (*March, 8th 2013*), git supports ** in `.gitignore` files, so using `test/**/Output/` will ignore only Output sub-directories under test directory.

Comment: This is a more elegant solution than the accepted answer.