# .gitignore subdirs not ignored properly

Tags: git

I have a series of school projects that I manage using git. The folder structure is as follows, minus fluff:

```
MainDir/Lab [#]/Lab [#].cache/
```

Where `[#]` represents each lab number. I want to ignore the `/Lab [#].cache/` directories. The .gitignore file is in MainDir, and I want to know the syntax for ignoring all the cache files.

Things I have tried:

```
**/*.cache    
**/*.cache/
**/Lab ?.cache/
*.cache
*cache/
```

I feel like I'm on the wrong track here. I've looked at the official documentation, as well as other questions like [.gitignore: How do I ignore nested directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685134/gitignore-how-do-i-ignore-nested-directories), which looked like it should solve the problem, but it didn't.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to ignore any `Lab [#].cache/` folder with:

```
*.cache/
```

Note the final '/', important to ignore a folder.

However, make sure that folder content is not already tracked:

```
git rm -r --cache MainDir/Lab 1/Lab 1.cache/
```

Then make sure the `.gitignore` rule works:

```
git check-ignore -v -- MainDir/Lab 1/Lab 1.cache/aFile
```

Comment: Thought I tried it. Weird that it didn't work before. Thanks though.